# Is there a playground tool for SiddhiQL

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

What is the easiest method to learn SiddhiQL. Is there any tool such as [Esper EPL Online](http://www.esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html) for Siddhi ? Or what is the most easy way for a beginner ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess 'Siddhi Try It' under 'tools' provides this help.

Comment: Please find the docs for help https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Siddhi+Try+It+Tool you have to use WSO2 CEP 4.0.0 for this.